# Similer like request.getContextPath() in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to know that,how we can get the current url path (e.g. http://www.mywebsite.com/) in asp.net.
I found that java have the **request.getContextPath()** to get that.
Even in dot net we have this,
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath

Is there any other ways that will gives the same result.

I am also interested to know how I will use the code in aspx page.

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this :)

```
http://<%=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host+System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath%>/page.aspx
```

cheers :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is the [HttpRequest.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.apprelativecurrentexecutionfilepath) Property

The property gets the virtual path of the application root and makes it relative by using the tilde (~) notation for the application root (as in "~/page.aspx").

Answer (score 0):

Could context.Request.Url.ToString() do the trick your looking for?

```
context.Request.Url.ToString()
```

returns: "http://localhost:52550/myapp/somepage/"